# Capistrano Prompting for Project Domain Name

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

I'm currently using Capistrano along with the multistage extension to manage deployments. Even after setting :domain in config/deploy/stage.rb, when calling 'cap stage deploy', its prompting me for a domain name for the project. What setting am missing?

Here is my deploy.rb

```
set :stages, %w(vm rtpstage ciscostage ciscodemo hp)

require 'deprec'
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
require 'lib/monit_recipes'

set :application, "systems"
set :repository,  "git://github.com/mdwrigh2/systems.git"


# If you aren't using Subversion to manage your source code, specify
# your SCM below:
set :scm, :git

set :user, "rails"
default_run_options[:pty] = true


set :ruby_vm_type,      :mri        # :ree, :mri
set :web_server_type,   :apache     # :apache, :nginx
set :app_server_type,   :mongrel  # :passenger, :mongrel
set :db_server_type,    :mysql      # :mysql, :postgresql, :sqlite


# set :packages_for_project, %w(libmagick9-dev imagemagick libfreeimage3) # list of packages to be installed
# set :gems_for_project, %w(rmagick mini_magick image_science) # list of gems to be installed

# Update these if you're not running everything on one host.

# If you aren't deploying to /opt/apps/#{application} on the target
# servers (which is the deprec default), you can specify the actual location
# via the :deploy_to variable:
# set :deploy_to, "/opt/apps/#{application}"

namespace :deploy do
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    top.deprec.app.restart
  end
end
```

---

And here is my vm.rb

```
set :domain, "juicy.vm"
role :app, "juicy.vm"
role :web, "juicy.vm"
role :db,  "juicy.vm", :primary => true
role :monitor, "juicy.vm"
```

Comment: Can you post your deploy.rb and stage.rb?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing (cos I've not used that multistage extension), but shouldn't you put the actual stage in the cap command? eg if your stage is called vm, then should you type "cap vm deploy" instead of "cap stage deploy" ???

Comment: Sorry, when I said stage, I mean the generic stage. So if I was deploying vm, it would indeed be `cap vm deploy`. I never did get this figured out. I assume it was a bug in Capistrano.

Comment: Ah - well darn, guess it isn't that easy... sometimes it is :)